# I have a broken impeller on a water pump 2002 Mitsubishi Galant

Tags: cooling-system, mitsubishi, galant

When I took out the water pump I seen that the impeller was broken and it was no peaces that fell out what should I do

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I think the obvious answer is purchase a new one and replace it (or have it replaced)? Not trying to be flippant, but this seems very straight forward.

Comment: Replace it... no other decision really.

Comment: Are you asking if there's a danger that pieces of the impeller got in your engine?

Comment: The broken pieces likely settled in the block and will not be a problem. Also, it would be very difficult to try to remove them from the water jacket.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a broken water pump, it must be replaced. This is the heart of your coolant system, without which your car will almost certainly destructively overheat. With poor flow, local hot spots will build up and likely break your car much worse than a broken water pump on its own.

It's hard to anticipate the specifics but I know that on my car the turbo would almost certainly fry first.